# Netbeans, android-maven-plugin and using apklib/aar dependencies

Tags: android, maven, netbeans, apklib, aar

I built my own android libs in aar/apklib format and I am now looking for a way to use them in the final apk project within netbeans without breaking the maven build. Problem is: I need to include the produced lib jars in order to make netbeans happy about finding imports for the libs, however that breaks the maven build because dex finds duplicate build configs because the libs have been specified twice in pom.xml (once as apklib/aar and once as jar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the .jar dependency to provided scope fixes the issue.

Comment: Finally! This solution works for third-party `aar` dependencies with android-maven-plugin as well.

Comment: Can you please explain "Setting the .jar dependency to provided scope" in more detail?

Comment: pom.xml -> dependency section -> <scope>provided</scope>